# Discrete Math Proofs Involving Real Numbers

Tags: real-numbers

I am stuck on these two problems.

$1$. Prove that for every three positive real numbers a, b, and c that

$(a+b+c)*(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}) \ge 9$.

$2$. Prove that for every three positive real numbers a, b, and c that 
$a^2 + b^2 + c^2  \ge ab + bc + ac$.

I have tried direct proof and have not gotten anywhere significant. I won't put the work on there since it is way too long and I don't think it will help. There must be some sort of trick involved, but for the life of me, I cannot figure it out.

Comment: The questions seem either incomplete, or badly translated.

Comment: Sorry, what is confusing about it? I copied the question directly from the original source and it is translated correctly. Please explain further so I can make necessary adjustments.

Comment: Have you proved the Arithmetic Mean Harmonic Mean Inequality? Or AM/GM?

Comment: You need to remove the "such that."

Comment: Froggy, "For every X such that Y" is just giving a condition Y on the object X. You didn't tell us what we need to prove about X.

Comment: Thanks. Then, the question must not be correctly written. Thank you anyways!

Comment: A "trick" for (2) is to look at $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2$.

Comment: What exactly is the "discrete math" part of this question?

Comment: How come no one has mentioned Cauchy-Schwarz for the $1$st ineqality? This is a very obvious application of it. Does that have something to do with the "discrete math" part? I am not very sure what you mean by saying "discrete math".

Comment: The last paragraph is irrelevant and makes the question longer.  There is no need to add junk to questions just to placate the users opposed to "homework".  (1) is the arithmetic mean - harmonic mean inequality for 3 variables.  (2) is true without the condition that $a,b,c$ be positive (changing signs does not change the left side but can reduce the right side). Inequality (2) for all real values of $a,b,c$ is the positive-definiteness of a quadratic form, which is equivalent to the ability to write the form as a sum of squares of linear forms, in this case $\sum (a-b)^2$.

Answer (score 6):

Hints:

1) Without loss of generality, $a\le b\le c$. Then $(a+b+c)\cdot (\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})= 3 + \frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{c}{b}$. Which of these ratios is at least $1$?

2) play with $(\pm a \pm b \pm c)^2\ge 0$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am confused about the ratios. Can you please elaborate further?

Comment: Oh I got it. Wow, that is brilliant.

Answer (score 4):

For (2), use the fact that
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 \ge 0.$$

For (1), use the hint of Ittay Weiss, and the fact that if $x$ is positive, then $x+\frac{1}{x}\ge 2$. This follows from the fact that 
$$x+\frac{1}{x}-2=\left(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2.$$

Comment: Or for the less inspired among us, $x+\frac1x\geq2$ (weak inequality!) for $x>0$ follows from study of the extrema of the function $x\mapsto x+\frac1x$.

Answer (score 3):

For $(1)$ $$a+b+c\ge 3(abc)^{\frac13}$$ and $$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\ge3 \frac1{(abc)^{\frac13}}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$(1)$:Use $\frac{(a+b+c)}{3}\geq \frac{3}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}$

$(2)$: Multiply by $2$: $2a^2 + 2b^2 + 2c^2 -2ab -2bc - 2ac\geq 0$