# Prove this statement?

Tags: real-numbers

I am having trouble with the following proof:

Prove that for every three positive real numbers a, b, and c that

$(a+b+c)*(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}) \ge 9$.

I have tried to directly prove this but all I get are dead ends.

Comment: This question was [recently asked and answered.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674622/discrete-math-proofs-involving-real-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is an answer by a different method of those given by the link of André Nicolas.*

By **Cauchy-Schwarz inequality** we have
$$\left(\sum_i a_i b_i\right)^2\le \left(\sum_i a_i^2\right)\left(\sum_i b_i^2\right)$$
so it suffices to take $a_i=\sqrt a$ and $b_i=b^{-1/2}$ and we have the desired result.